# Passing pattern to url

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to map two or more seller to the same method `ecommerce.views.seller`. Below is the working code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?:store1|store3)/$', 'ecommerce.views.seller'),
)
```

Is there any way by which I can declare some variable with pattern and simply pass it into urlpatterns. Something like:

```
SELLER_ID = '?:store1|store3'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(SELLER_ID)/$', 'ecommerce.views.seller'),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regular string formatting syntax:

```
url(r'^({})/$'.format(SELLER_ID), 'ecommerce.views.seller')
```

Comment: For: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/store1/`  TypeError at /store1/

seller() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @Samuel Then there is something wrong with how you defined `seller` view.

Comment: `r'^({})/$'.format("store1|store3")` produces the same string. You can test it out in shell.

Comment: Yes ozgur, my bad. Thanks for the quick reply buddy :) . Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use capturing groups for regex path variables in order to have them provided as keyword arguments in your view method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments

There is a very short example at the above link.

What you would probably want to do:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^store(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 'ecommerce.views.seller'),
)
```

in ecommerce/views.py:

```
def seller(request, pk):
    seller = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=pk)  # if DB object
    # or if not in DB then just use the number
    # do your stuff
    return response
```

or use a generic view if the PK points to a DB model:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^store(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', StoreDetailView.as_view(), name='store_detail'),
)

class StoreDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Store
    # the rest is django magic, you just have to provide the template
```